# "The hotel at which we stayed" & "The hotel in which we stayed"

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

Are both of them correct? If they are, what's the difference?

> The hotel **at** which we stayed
>
> The hotel **in** which we stayed

Comment: You want to ask "Are both of them correct?"

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stay **at** or **in** a hotel, so both are correct. If there is a nuanced difference,  **in** emphasizes the hotel as lodgings and **at** as a place or location one has visited.  Many speakers would detect no difference at all.